# Rollback Changes in MVC on Service Error C#

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have an MVC controller that calls to multiple different DB's from multiple services. If I have a controller method that needs to call say, 3 different service methods across 3 different services, what are the best practices for rolling back if that last service method fails? At this point, the first two service calls would have succeeded and been saved on their DBContexts but since these are different DBContexts, it doesn't seem like using a transaction is an option. What are some options for rolling back the other contexts if the last one fails?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have only available option: Saga pattern

> The saga pattern provides transaction management using a sequence of
> local transactions. A local transaction is the atomic work effort
> performed by a saga participant. Each local transaction updates the
> database and publishes a message or event to trigger the next local
> transaction in the saga. If a local transaction fails, the saga
> executes a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes
> that were made by the preceding local transactions.

You can read more detailed description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga) or [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

There are several sagas implementation available out of the box in .net, for example:
[MassTransit Sagas](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/)
[Chronicle](https://github.com/snatch-dev/Chronicle)